# Field has an Incomplete type?

Tags: c

I am getting an error regarding a struct element.

```
struct trie {
        char ch;
        bool isEnd;
        struct trie arr[4];
        struct trie *next;
};
```

Error:

```
error: field ‘arr’ has incomplete type
```

Comment: you have to forward declare `trie`. otherwise its incomplete type when it tries to use itself within the struct

Comment: @amdixon Won't solve the issue. a `struct` can't contain itself.

Comment: So your trie contains four tries, which will each contain four tries, which each contain four tries, ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define your struct this way

```
struct trie {
    char ch;
    bool isEnd;
    struct trie *arr[4];
    struct trie *next;
};
```

Note that (to avoid an infinite recursion) arr is now an array of four **pointers** each one is referring to a **trie** structure that you'll have to allocate dynamically on your code.

You can allocate a **trie** (uninitialized, of course) with this function:

```
struct trie *alloc_trie() {
    return malloc(sizeof(struct trie));
}
```

Note that the four **trie** pointed by the four items of **arr** are not allocated. Neither is **next**.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a structure in itself (just think about it, it doesn't make sense). It would cause "infinite recursion" regarding the type. Maybe you can get away with another pointer to `struct trie` for which you can allocate memory dynamically. But I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you want an array of pointers? `struct trie *arr[4]` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Forward declare like:

```
typedef struct trie trie;

struct trie {
  char ch; 
  int isEnd; //bool unsupported for c89 so..
  trie *arr; //have to manually alloc 4 trie here..
  trie *next;
};
```

*Edit*: removed underscore from naming as indicated in section `7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers` of c99 draft standard [indicated in comments]

Comment: forward declaration isn't the problem. The problem is the array (which you've removed in your answer).

Comment: No need to forward declare. `struct _trie * next` would do the job.

Comment: Identifiers (or `struct` tags) in global scope that start with an `_` are a "no no". Just using `trie` for both would do the trick.

Comment: @JensGustedt think thatd be down to preference. but naming the struct with `_` prefix is often done in this sort of context where you typedef with a _nicer_ name.

Comment: @amdixon no, that's not "preference". Prefixing global names with underscores is reserved for the implementation; any user code doing this has undefined behavior.